# Why does the screen when disparity is output distorted via opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

First, I am a Korean who does not speak English.

Because I used Google's translation due to lack of English skills,

Please acknowledge it beforehand

.

I want to obtain disparity via opencv.

I asked for a corner using the "findChessboardCorners" function for the predecessor task.

We calibrated the stereo camera using the following coordinate values.

.

After finishing the screen correction, after seeing diparity, it looks only noise.

Why ?

```
// this function is get diparity
int getDisparity(Mat leftImg, Mat rightImg)
{
    // value null check
    if (leftImg.empty() || rightImg.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    int SADWindowSize, numberOfDisparities;
    //bool no_display;
    //float scale;

    // default variable
    numberOfDisparities = 16;//16;// 192;
    SADWindowSize = 3;//3;// 64;


    Ptr<StereoSGBM> sgbm = StereoSGBM::create(0, numberOfDisparities, SADWindowSize);

    Mat img1 = leftImg;
    Mat img2 = rightImg;

    // get view size
    Size img_size = img1.size();

    numberOfDisparities = numberOfDisparities > 0 ? numberOfDisparities : ((img_size.width / 8) + 15) & -16;

    // set sgbm parameters
    sgbm->setPreFilterCap(63);
    int sgbmWinSize = SADWindowSize > 0 ? SADWindowSize : 3;
    sgbm->setBlockSize(sgbmWinSize);

    int cn = img1.channels();

    sgbm->setP1(8 * cn*sgbmWinSize*sgbmWinSize);
    sgbm->setP2(32 * cn*sgbmWinSize*sgbmWinSize);
    sgbm->setMinDisparity(0);
    sgbm->setNumDisparities(numberOfDisparities);
    sgbm->setUniquenessRatio(10);
    sgbm->setSpeckleWindowSize(100);
    sgbm->setSpeckleRange(32);
    sgbm->setDisp12MaxDiff(1);
    sgbm->setMode(StereoSGBM::MODE_SGBM);

    Mat disp, disp8;

    // Disparity
    sgbm->compute(img1, img2, disp);

    // convert type
    disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8U, 255 / (numberOfDisparities*16.));

    // show
    namedWindow("left image", 1);
    imshow("left image", img1);
    namedWindow("right image", 1);
    imshow("right image", img2);

    cv::cvtColor(disp8, disparityMap, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

     // disparity show
    namedWindow("disparity", 0);
    imshow("disparity", disparityMap);

    waitKey(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The image below is what I used.

[left image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJOFl.jpg)

[right image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWCmg.jpg)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtB6d.jpg)

[sample image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4qrA.jpg)

Comment: I think your input images is not that suitable for disparity.

Comment: @Silencer What should I do? (Add sample image 2)

Comment: Exactly as @Silencer says your images seem to be not ready for disparity computation. You may also want to read [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1117/how-to-obtain-stereo-correspondences-and-what-exactly-is-a-disparity-map)

Comment: Another thing: when calibrating, the chessboard pattern must be glued on a flat surface. You cannot just print it on a sheet of paper and hold it by hand.